# Custom Force Directed Graph (D3)

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I have a crazy idea and I don't know where to begin with it.

I want to make a force directed graph with D3 that actually will render the nodes everything looking as a piece of text.

This is the Force Directed Graph: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

This is what I have in mind: https://www.dropbox.com/s/26keicwdzzw91x8/Screenshot%202014-02-05%2001.47.43.png

I know that I have to structure the data connections in a specific way, but I have no idea where to begin with.

Not necesarilly that complex name, but to actually render a few letter looking like connected nodes that can be dragged.

Comment: Or an alternative to this kind of behavior is welcomed. My mind is jammed.

Comment: If you start with an SVG font (or [convert a font to SVG](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/font-converter.html)), you could probably write a program to parse the path directions for each letter to assign your node positions.  If you're not familiar with how SVG paths are defined, [this might help](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/pIder): you can take a look at my [path-parsing code on this page](http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/LjHov) to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to play with it this afternoon!